# I am Getting this "A nullable expression can't be used as a condition."

Tags: flutter

I Created this form to submit the data to API.

But something is wrong there is an error. i declared the variable nullable still this error came to me.

I don't know what's the problem.

**Note**: I don't only want to solve this error but I want to understand what I missed.

Could you please explain??

```
  bool? error, sending, success;
  String? msg;
  Future<void> sendData() async {
    var phpurl = Uri.parse("https://homeshouse.000webhostapp.com/create.php");

    var res = await http.post(phpurl, body: {
      "name": namectl.text,
      "desciption": desciptionctl.text,
      "addr": addrctl.text,
      "image_url": image_urlctl.text,
      "price": pricectl.text,
    }); //sending post request with header data

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print(res.body); //print raw response on console

      var data = json.decode(res.body); //decoding json to array
      if (data["error"]) {
        setState(() {
          //refresh the UI when error is recieved from server
          sending = false;
          error = true;
          msg = data["message"]; //error message from server
        });
      } else {
        namectl.text = "";
        desciptionctl.text = "";
        addrctl.text = "";
        image_urlctl.text = "";
        pricectl.text = "";
        //after write success, make fields empty

        setState(() {
          sending = false;
          success = true; //mark success and refresh UI with setState
        });
      }
    } else {
      //there is error
      setState(() {
        error = true;
        msg = "Error during sendign data.";
        sending = false;
        //mark error and refresh UI with setState
      });
    }
  }

                              setState(() {
                                sending = true;
                              });
                              await sendData();
                                clearfields();
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              sending? "Sending...":"SEND DATA",
                              // "Sending",
                              //if sending == true then show "Sending" else show "SEND DATA";
                            ),
                            // color: Colors.redAccent,
                            // colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                            //background of button is darker color, so set brightness to dark
                          )))
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sending` can be null, and Dart doesn't see null as a falsy value able to be used inside a ternary. You can rewrite your ternary like this if you're sure that `sending` isn't null at this point:

```
sending! ? "Sending..." : "SEND DATA",
```

Or, if you're not sure whether it's null or not.

```
sending == true ? "Sending..." : "SEND DATA",
```

Comment: You should prefer `sending ?? false` over `sending == true` since the former makes it clear that it's accounting for `null`, and equality (or inequality) comparisons to `true` or `false` are usually a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `error, sending, success, msg` all these variables are optional means you may get value or null as a value.

Dart doesn't consider the null value as false. You need to give true are false values only.

Updated Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//import package file manually

void main() => runApp(const ListHouse());

class ListHouse extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListHouse({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red, //primary color for theme
        ),
        home: WriteSQLdata() //set the class here
        );
  }
}

class WriteSQLdata extends StatefulWidget {
  const WriteSQLdata({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return WriteSQLdataState();
  }
}

class WriteSQLdataState extends State<WriteSQLdata> {
  //text controller for TextField
  TextEditingController namectl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController desciptionctl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController addrctl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController image_urlctl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pricectl = TextEditingController();

  bool? error, sending, success;
  String? msg;

  // do not use http://localhost/ for your local
  // machine, Android emulation do not recognize localhost
  // insted use your local ip address or your live URL
  // hit "ipconfig" on Windows or  "ip a" on Linux to get IP Address

  @override
  void initState() {
    error = false;
    sending = false;
    success = false;
    msg = '';
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> sendData() async {
    var phpurl = Uri.parse('https://homeshouse.000webhostapp.com/create.php');

    var res = await http.post(phpurl, body: {
      'name': namectl.text,
      'desciption': desciptionctl.text,
      'addr': addrctl.text,
      'image_url': image_urlctl.text,
      'price': pricectl.text,
    }); //sending post request with header data

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print(res.body); //print raw response on console

      var data = json.decode(res.body); //decoding json to array
      if (data['error']) {
        setState(() {
          //refresh the UI when error is recieved from server
          sending = false;
          error = true;
          msg = data['message']; //error message from server
        });
      } else {
        namectl.text = '';
        desciptionctl.text = '';
        addrctl.text = '';
        image_urlctl.text = '';
        pricectl.text = '';
        //after write success, make fields empty

        setState(() {
          sending = false;
          success = true; //mark success and refresh UI with setState
        });
      }
    } else {
      //there is error
      setState(() {
        error = true;
        msg = 'Error during sendign data.';
        sending = false;
        //mark error and refresh UI with setState
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('List Your House'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent), //appbar

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          //enable scrolling, when keyboard appears,
          // hight becomes small, so prevent overflow
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(error == true ? msg ?? '' : 'Enter House Information'),

                  Text(success == true ? 'Write Success' : 'send data'),

                  TextField(
                    controller: namectl,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'House Name:',
                      hintText: 'Enter House name',
                    ),
                  ), //text input for name

                  TextField(
                    controller: desciptionctl,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'desciption:',
                      hintText: 'Enter house desciption',
                    ),
                  ), //text input for address

                  TextField(
                    controller: addrctl,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'address:',
                      hintText: 'Enter house address',
                    ),
                  ), //text input for class

                  TextField(
                    controller: image_urlctl,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'House Image:',
                      hintText: 'Enter image_urlctl url',
                    ),
                  ), //text input for roll no
                  TextField(
                    controller: pricectl,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'House price:',
                      hintText: 'Enter House price',
                    ),
                  ), //text input for roll nox

                  Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              //if button is pressed, setstate sending = true, so that we can show "sending..."

                              setState(() {
                                sending = true;
                              });
                              await sendData();
                              clearfields();
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              sending == true ? 'Sending...' : 'SEND DATA',
                              // "Sending",
                              //if sending == true then show "Sending" else show "SEND DATA";
                            ),
                            // color: Colors.redAccent,
                            // colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                            //background of button is darker color, so set brightness to dark
                          )))
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }

  void clearfields() {
    namectl.clear();
    desciptionctl.clear();
    addrctl.clear();
    image_urlctl.clear();
    pricectl.clear();
  }
}
```